# Change cells of all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with one sheet called company location. It has different names in each row in Column A. For instance A:1 is "Company A" A:2 is "Company B" etc...

I then have 20 worksheets that I've created as a template but I need to change cell A:2 on each worksheet to the next cell in the range between A1 and A20.

So Sheet 2 cell A2 should be the name listed in "Company" Sheet Cell A1. Then Sheet 3 cell A2 should be the name listed on "Company Sheet Cell A2" and so on and so on.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have one sheet called "Company" that's where all the companies are listed.

Comment: Then a sheet called "Template" and then 20 copies of "Template"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes worked for me.

```
Option Explicit
Sub work()
Dim company As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set company = Worksheets("company")
For i = 1 To 20
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
    Range("A2") = company.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

I called the first sheet "company" and there are exactly 20 Worksheets following the first sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget as Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("company location")
    ws.Activate

    'Loop through the rows
    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= 20

        'Set the target sheet to the next worksheet
        set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & lRow + 1)

        'Write the value from the company sheet
        wsTarget.Range("A" & lrow + 1).Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value

        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: No- that didn't work. It pasted the value in A3 of one sheet and A4 of another. I need the value from "Company" sheet to be pasted in cell A2 of "Template" sheet and all the copies I have of "Template"

Comment: And I modified to change the sheet to "Company" instead of "Company location" as in your example.